# Invalidate rails cache on copycopter translation update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have an rails 3 application and am using copycopter for managing translations. I started integrating caching into my app and now have a problem. As copycopter is a server-client app when you change an translation on server the client downloads the translations.

All my pages contain translatable strings I18n.t("some_key.something"), how can I expire cache when this translation changes(the updated key is downloaded from copycopter server)? What is the best practice when the translation is used in several pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigations I found a similar problem and it's solution can be applied also in this case.

Solution can be found here:

[How can the cache for the views with translations be invalidated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055056/how-can-the-cache-for-the-views-with-translations-be-invalidated)