# How can the cache for the views with translations be invalidated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, internationalization

Imagine you have two views with code like the following:

**controller_a/a.html.erb**

```
  <%= content_tag(:div) do %>
     <%= I18n.t "some.key" %>
  <% end %>
```

**controller_b/b.html.erb**

```
  <%= content_tag(:div) do %>
     <%= I18n.t "some.key" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= content_tag(:div) do %>
     <%= I18n.t "some.other_key" %>
  <% end %>
```

So, `a.html.erb` is on controller_a#a, while `b.html.erb` is on controller_b#b. Both actions are cached by `caches_action`. How can I make sure that when I change the `some.key` translation key, both views are invalidated? How could I build a generic mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say, in your `ApplicationController` create the following class-method (or in a lib and `extend` by it):

```
def self.i18n_digest(*scopes)
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest I18n.t(scopes).to_s
end
```

Then you can use `:cache_path` option in your `caches_action` this way:

```
caches_action :some_action, cache_path: { some_key: i18n_digest('some', 'foo') }
```

Just make sure that you set the locale in a `before_filter` before this statement.

[Docs on `cache_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html).

**Note:** I'm using the scope of translation (`'some'`) to get all its nested messages as a hash.

Comment: So this assumes that all keys in a view have the same prefix?

Comment: @Tempus Updated. Now you can pass multiple scopes.

Comment: Thank you! It's a very ingenious solution!

Comment: @Tempus By the way, I've remembered that I18t can accept an array of keys and return an array of hashes. Now you don't need even `map {...}`. See another update :-)

Comment: Also it's better to cache i18n_digest, because i18n is only changes on server reload, and we can use application memory to cache this cache.